# What is Local Reasoning , exactly?

Tags: functional-programming, side-effects, referential-transparency

What is Local Reasoning ? how does it relate to Referential Transparency, Equational Reasoning and Laziness ?

Comment: both terms have brief definitions in http://degoes.net/articles/fp-glossary

Answer (score 2):

(adding the definition from the commented link, just to avoid *link only answer*)

From http://degoes.net/articles/fp-glossary

*Local reasoning* is a property of some code wherein the correctness of the code can be inferred locally under specified assumptions, without considering prior application state or all possible inputs.